# Hazelcast, HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup'

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

I have created custom entry processor for updating map entries by extending `AbstractEntryProcessor`. 
When my app is running in a cluster on two instances, and the entry processor is executed I receive following exception:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup'
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:73)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:143)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:124)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.send(OperationServiceImpl.java:406)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendSingleBackup(OperationBackupHandler.java:187)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.makeBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:159)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.backup(OperationBackupHandler.java:78)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendBackup(OperationRunnerImpl.java:270)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:253)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:182)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:122)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:102)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PartitionWideEntryWithPredicateBackupOperation'
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:73)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:201)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:371)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup.writeInternal(Backup.java:222)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.writeData(Operation.java:472)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:161)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:52)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:140)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.map.AbstractEntryProcessor$EntryBackupProcessorImpl'
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:73)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:201)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:371)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PartitionWideEntryBackupOperation.writeInternal(PartitionWideEntryBackupOperation.java:98)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PartitionWideEntryWithPredicateBackupOperation.writeInternal(PartitionWideEntryWithPredicateBackupOperation.java:51)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.writeData(Operation.java:472)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:161)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:52)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:199)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:242)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:199)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

My entry processor is look like this:

```
public class HRUpdateRacesWithEntriesProcessor extends AbstractEntryProcessor<HRMeeting.HRMeetingKey, HRMeeting> {

  private List<HRRace> races;
  private Date date;

  public HRUpdateRacesWithEntriesProcessor(List<HRRace> races, Date date) {
    this.races = races;
    this.date = date;
  }

  @Override
  public Object process(Map.Entry<HRMeeting.HRMeetingKey, HRMeeting> entry) {
    HRMeeting meeting = entry.getValue();
    races.stream()
        .filter(race -> entry.getKey().equals(new HRMeeting.HRMeetingKey(race.getMeetingDate(), race.getCourseId())))
        .forEach(newRace -> {
          Optional<HRRace> matchedRace =
              meeting.getRaces().stream().filter(origin -> origin.getKey().equals(newRace.getKey())).findFirst();
          if (newRace.getEntries() != null && matchedRace.isPresent()) {
            newRace.setUpdateDate(date);
            newRace.getEntries().stream()
                .filter(hrEntry -> matchedRace.get().getEntries().stream().map(el -> el.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(hrEntry.getKey()))
                .forEach(hrEntry -> hrEntry.setUpdateDate(date));
            matchedRace.get().getEntries().retainAll(newRace.getEntries());
            newRace.getEntries().addAll(matchedRace.get().getEntries());
          }
          meeting.getRaces()
              .removeIf(hrRace -> matchedRace.isPresent() && matchedRace.get().getKey().equals(hrRace.getKey()));
          meeting.getRaces().add(newRace);
        });
    entry.setValue(meeting);
    return null;
  }
}
```

For serialization my entites implements java `Serializible`. Is is can be reason of the issue?

I am using hazelcast-3.8-SNAPSHOT

Please, help me to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a simple problem. I met the same error when tried to put an Object to IMap in Hazelcast. In my case, the object, which I try to put,  wasn't implements Serializable.

So, I think you should check you did implements Serializable in "com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup" like

public class Backup implements Serializable {
...
}

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that somehow (it actually hard to follow the stream flow) capture content from your EntryProcessor implementation and because of that it is tried to be serialized using Serializable. Anyhow DataSerializable / IdentifiedDataSerializable is not java.util.Serializable to prevent unexpected serialization (like in your case) from happening :)

My guess is the date:

`.forEach(hrEntry -> hrEntry.setUpdateDate(date));`

I hope this helps, you might have to look for the actually captured value.

Comment: I have comment this code `.forEach(hrEntry -> hrEntry.setUpdateDate(date));`, still get the same.

Comment: I am going to use `IdentifiedDataSerializable` for srialization. My entity is complicated objects, it consist of other onces. So should each of my entity implement `DataSerializableFactory`? And should  the implementation of the `DataSerializableFactory` be separate for each entity?

Comment: This won't solve your actual issue, you're still going to serialize too much. I would recommend to find the actual problem not working around it. It'll save lots of traffic. - Otherwise yeah Factory and implementation for the serialization - than register it on startup